# How to show column name from impala datamart

Tags: python, pandas, database, impala

Basically, my company using apache impala for datamart.

connection args are define before and connection is define as `conn = connect(host=host_name, port=port, user=user, password=password, database=database)`

Everytime I need a table I need to call a function like this

```
def impala_connection(host, port, user, password, database):
    conn = connect(host=host_name, port=port, user=user, password=password, database=database)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * from table1')
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    return results
table1 = pd.DataFrame(impala_connection(host_name, port, user,password, database))
```

when I call `table1` my dataframe will look like this

```
      0     1    2    3    4
0     a     b    c    d    e
1     e     f    g    g    i
```

Actually the table has column name, how to show that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read a limit lines from database use `pd.read_sql`. and from `df.columns` to get the table column names.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

conn = create_engine(
    'impala://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}'.format(
        host=host,    # your host
        port=port,
        database=database,
        user=user,
        password=password
    )

sql_read = lambda sql: pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
sql_execute = lambda sql: pd.io.sql.execute(sql, conn)

sql = '''
select *
from table1
limit 1
'''
df = sql_read(sql)
print(df.columns)
```

Comment: File `"<ipython-input-73-1309ee172688>"`, line 13
    `sql_read = lambda sql: pd.read_sql(sql, conn)`
    ^
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`